# Ajax DataType: JSON respond is: OK but No output?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Okay so here is my problem. I have a simple jQuery Ajax request and I can't get is work when I set the DataType to "JSON".

```
    var form_data = { "id": msg, "token": token };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend:function(){
            // this is where we append a loading image
        },
        success: function(data) { 
            var thing = JSON.parse(data);
            $('.body-item').html(thing.b);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

This is my ajax file actually. The `ajax.php` looks like this:

```
            $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

            $foo = json_encode($arr);
            echo $foo;
```

When I run the jQuery script, I got a 200:OK response with Firebug, and when I take a look at the response I got the following: `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`

However I do NOT get anything showed in the .body-item div, nor if I try with alert().

Also if I run the same code WITHOUT the: `dataType: 'json'` part, I get everything outputted correctly.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Try $('.body-item').html(data.b);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery calls `JSON.parse()` and puts the result in `data`. You shouldn't call it yourself, since `data` is not a JSON string, it's the parsed object. So just do:

```
$('body-item').html(data.b);
```

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you for the answer. It's working like a charm. I have never ever thought about that. Will be accepted as an answer in 8 minutes. Thank you again!

Comment: I thought it was to tell jQuery to expect a strict JSON type of data and nothing else. I dind't actually think that it should not be converted. But it's obvious as I read it again. I don't know I must have misunderstood something here. But thanks to you everything is crystal clear now! :)