# How to use jQuery to get data from a json_encode data in the php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, get

I am a newbie in coding. I am trying to display all the pictures in the database on the client side. I could do that on my php file, but I couldn't get the json_encode data with jQuery. 
Could somebody help me? Thank you in advance!

Here is my PHP code:

```
foreach ($pictures as $picture){
      $photos = "<p><img src='".$picture['link']."' width='200' height='200'></p><p id='title'>".$picture['title']."</p><p id='descr'>".$picture['descr']."</p>";
      echo json_encode($photos);
}
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({                                      
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'server/picture_client.php',        
        dataType: 'json',                  
        success: function(photos){     
        if(photos){
            var data = $.parseJSON(photos);
            $("#grid").append(data);

        }else{
            alert("oops nothing happened :(");
        }        
    }
```

Thank you again!

Comment: What's the problem? What happens?

Comment: Don't call `$.parseJSON`. jQuery does that for you when you specify `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Your JSON doesn't make any sense.  If you just want to echo a string of HTML, there is no reason to use JSON.  If not, JSON cannot be concatenated like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax DataType: JSON respond is: OK but No output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236566/ajax-datatype-json-respond-is-ok-but-no-output)

Comment: I used .get() for my first attempt to get the data echo-ed in my php file. And that was a success, but then it will also get other echo-ed strings in the same php file...so I did some research and tried .ajax() and json_encode...but that way did not get me anything displayed on my html client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need json in this case you can just send the html:

```
foreach ($pictures as $picture){
      $photos .= "<p><img src='".$picture['link']."' width='200' height='200'></p><p id='title'>".$picture['title']."</p><p id='descr'>".$picture['descr']."</p>";
}
echo $photos;
```

Then append the html to your element:

```
$.ajax({                 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'server/picture_client.php',        
    dataType: 'html',                  
    success: function(photos){     
    if(photos){
        $("#grid").append(photos);

    }else{
        alert("oops nothing happened :(");
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've provided `dataType: 'json'`, you don't need to do `$.parseJSON` your data again, you can just use:

```
$("#grid").append(photos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 foreach ($pictures as $picture){
  $photos[] = "<p><img src='".$picture['link']."' width='200' height='200'></p><p id='title'>".$picture['title']."</p><p id='descr'>".$picture['descr']."</p>";      
 }
echo json_encode('photos' => $photos);
```

jquery:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'server/picture_client.php',        
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results){  
       $.each(results.photos, function(i, item) {
         $("#grid").append(item);
       });​ 
    }
});
```